# Who put Thor in chains?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

In the beginning of *Thor: Ragnarok* movie, we see Thor in chains in the den of Surtur.

I know that Thor got captured by choice (he says), but who put him there?

Comment: Did you miss Surtur's evil minions in **literally the same scene**?

Comment: @Valorum Those minions looked like savage beasts without any intelligence. I doubt they would have captured Thor.

Comment: @Discovery Its clear from the scene that Thor let himself be captured to get close enough to his goal.

Comment: @Vahx Read the question again..

Comment: @Bat I have to admit I am confused too. Thor got himself captured on purpose. Even to say that the evil minion creatures are not intelligent (which we do not know) it is not that hard to hold a chain and walk around someone that is standing still... Not to mention that unless it is shown to be covered somewhere else (comics, deleted scene, etc.) there is no way for us to go beyond speculation and know a "throw away set up" scene such as that.

Comment: I don't think we need a warning for something that's in the trailer and occurs within the first two minutes of the film.

Comment: “Those minions looked like savage beasts without any intelligence” — I mean, so does Hemsworth.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite But, he speaks. Better than Jar Jar.

Comment: @user931: we were talking about looks, and while I’m not sure what relevance Jar-Jar has here, he speaks differently, but perfectly.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite You seriously didn't understand the joke here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The film's novelisation (translated below from the Russian because I can't find my copy in English) clearly indicates that the fire demons are not merely mindless minions for Thor to mince with Mjölnir, but thinking sentient beings who are more than capable of taking Thor and throwing him in a cage after he surrenders to them.

> The fire demon's voice crackled with the echo of hellfire: “We do not favor your kindred in our land, Asgardian.
> “Anything is possible, but I was walking nearby, so I thought, why not drop in and say “Hello!,” Thor said in a casual tone.
> The fire demons looked at each other, not sure how to respond to that. Humor was a rare guest in Muspelheim. It must have disappeared like smoke, along with all the rest of the contents of the Kingdom of Fire.
> Finally, the demon said: “Hold on a moment longer, Asgardian, and greet death. Your own.
> “Not today,” Thor replied, tightening his grip on Mjolnir.
> It was then that the fire demons pounced on him.
>
> <sub><sup>[Thor: Ragnarok - The Junior Novel](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Thor:_Ragnarok:_The_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

Comment: “translated below from the Russian because I can't find my copy in English” — it’s reassuring to see that Valorum doesn’t just read the _English_  novelisation of every single movie like some lightweight fly-by-night fairweather nerd, but also covers other major languages.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - My Russian is very shaky indeed. I know just about enough to get myself killed in a bar by asking for a 'shotgun in the face' rather than 'a mug of beer"

Comment: @Valorum You want стакан пиво and not ружю в морду. For future reference.